# Epson PosPrinter (TM-T70) keeps creating Threads on connection attempts

Tags: java, epson

I am trying to work with an Epson TM-T70 Pos-Printer. Printing works, but in case the Printer is offline, I am trying to reconnect in a loop.
The following happens in the constructor of the printer-control-object until I run into an exception:

```
private POSPrinterControl19 epsonPrinterControl19;
epsonPrinterControl19 = (POSPrinterControl19) new POSPrinter();
epsonPrinterControl19.open(printerName);
epsonPrinterControl19.claim(0);
```

On claim, a JPos-Exception is thrown, the constructor does not construct. On the Object, the finalize-method is called:

```
    super.finalize();
    epsonPrinterControl19.removeStatusUpdateListener(this);
    epsonPrinterControl19 = null;
```

What remains running, though, is a Thread:

```
"EPSON UPOS Service EventThread.@2472" prio=5 tid=0x14 nid=NA waiting
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
  at jp.co.epson.upos.ServiceEventQueue.peekEvent(Unknown Source:-1)
  at jp.co.epson.upos.ServiceEventThread.run(Unknown Source:-1)
```

I seem unable to get rid of this Thread. And because I retry connecting to the printer from the main program around this, new Threads keep being created.
The question is: How do I get rid of those Threads?

Edit: I experimented some more... it seems the problem is caused by new POSPrinter(); which created this Thread.
Personally, I am now on another Problem... I will need to think about if this question is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone knows how to *get rid* of the Threads (instead of preventing them) please, do answer :).

For the actual problem: turns out that with calls to new POSPrinter() a Thread is being created, and remains active (though waiting) no matter of the PosPrinter-Object remains referenced or not.

The solution (at the moment) seems to be to make sure the Constructor is only called once, and do all operations for reconnecting, disconnecting and so on on that one object.
(It seems cleaner programming to me, anyway.)